# Общий пояснительный союз "то есть"

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, однородные-члены, пояснительные

Конструкция:

> Небо казалось нереальным, то есть синие разводы выглядели
>   акварельными, облака катались по глади рисованными барашками и даже дождь
>   будто шел алмазный, ненастоящий.

Уточнено у автора: все включённые в конструкцию предложения поясняют первое ("небо казалось нереальным, то есть даже дождь был ненастоящим"). Можно ли считать союз общим второстепенным членом? Нужна ли запятая перед "и даже", если оно по смыслу объединено? Здесь как бы все предложения, начиная с "то есть", являются однородными пояснениями.

Comment: Опечатка, сейчас поправлю, спасибо.

Comment: Если вы считаете приемлемой такую фразу:
Небо казалось нереальным, то есть дождь будто шел алмазный.
То все в порядке. Если нет, то нет. P.S. В повседневной речи мы часто слышим предложение: Да, то есть нет.

Comment: В художественном тексте считаю такое допустимым и приемлемым.

Answer (score 1):

Союз "то есть" нельзя считать общим, так как он относится ко второй части сложного предложения и поясняет, что будет описываться дальше.

Запятая перед "даже" ставится, несмотря на смысловое объединение. Ведь в одной части ("облака катались по глади рисованными барашками") говорится об облаках, а в другой ("дождь будто даже шел алмазный") о дожде.

Answer (score 1):

Дождь небом не является, поэтому последняя часть не связана с первой. Дождь идёт с неба, то есть оно связано косвенно, а не напрямую. Эту часть можно оформить отдельным предложением. Так что запятая нужна.

"Даже" указывает на присоединительную интонацию, при которой ставится запятая.

"То есть" используется для точного объяснения смысла слова/фразы, это как уточнение. Оно не должно использоваться вместо "потому что" (это даже стилистическая ошибка). Здесь лучше просто поставить двоеточие. Ещё можно использовать "из-за того что".