# Может ли общий элемент соединять три простых предложения в составе сложного?

Tags: запятые, сложное-предложение, и

1. Имеется в виду, что обычно общий элемент соединяет **два простых предложения** в составе ССП при наличии одиночного союза И, и тогда запятая между ними не ставится. (Это делается по аналогии **с однородными членами**.) Только такие примеры есть **у Розенталя** в этой теме, поэтому я была уверена, что речь всегда идет о двух предложениях.
2. Но на форуме довольно часто встречаются вопросы об общем элементе, когда в заданном примере присутствуют **три предложения**, а союз И является замыкающим для них. Это никого не удивляет ― более того, наши участники тоже склонны **не замечать** таких особенностей. Поэтому я (под давлением общества) уже начинаю сомневаться в своем понимании темы.
3. В качестве примера приведу предложение, где обсуждается возможность союза ***то есть*** быть общим:

***Небо казалось нереальным**, **то есть** синие разводы выглядели акварельными, облака катались по глади рисованными барашками и даже дождь будто шел алмазный, ненастоящий.*
[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458523/Общий-пояснительный-союз-то-есть](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458523/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

4. **И вопрос**: позволяют ли какие-либо **правила** считать союз И замыкающим для **трех предложений** и при наличии общего элемента не ставить запятую? (Также по аналогии **с однородными** членами.)

Comment: Конечно может. Мы же это уже обсуждали, три примера из справочников давал. Вы забыли?

Comment: "То есть" здесь не подходит. См.: *Небо казалось нереальным, то есть в это трудно было поверить.* А там раскрытие содержания через "то есть", так нельзя. И дождь — это не небо, поэтому присоединение, запятая ставится.

Comment: "То есть" меня в данном случае не интересует. Ответьте на вопрос: приведите четкое правило и примеры из классиков, и будет вам благодарность. Почему у Розенталя нет ни одного примера?

Comment: Мы это обсуждали здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467027

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Розенталя есть два примера с более чем двумя элементами:
*У Гаврилы смешно надулись щёки, оттопырились губы и суженные глаза как-то чересчур часто и смешно помаргивали* (Горький).
*Тишина, темнота, одиночество и этот странный шум* (Симонов).
У Лопатина один:
*К полудню черные облака почти коснутся земли, задует сырой ветер и польются томительные, нагоняющие сон обложные дожди* (Паустовский).

Comment: Спасибо!  Односоставные предложения я видела, но это особый случай. Правила, наверное, нет?

Comment: В правилах не сказано о количестве, то есть ограничений нет.

Comment: Не сказано. А вот общей фонетической фразы здесь не получится – чисто семантический признак. На слове "губы" приходится делать ударение, а это верная пауза, а общее обстоятельство относится к первому предложению. Впрочем, для однородных членов то же самое, но там Лопатин добавил правило, хоть что-то полезное сделал. Ладно, будем равняться на классические примеры  из литературы.

Comment: У меня получается читать в одну фразу. *Впрочем, для однородных членов то же самое* — как раз хотел об этом сказать. Ну там "у Гаврилы" общее.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за ответ, вроде  бы ситуация прояснилась.